# Django can't find a file stored in my application folder

Tags: python, django

I have a folder that stores a json file in my django application folder, ie, `test_data/data.json`.

In my `tests.py`, I am trying to read this file using the following code:

```
with open('/test_data/data.json', 'r') as f:
    self.response_data = json.load(f)
```

However, I keep on getting the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/test_data/data.json'`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Edit: I tried removing the leading slash, yet I still get the same error.

Comment: You here use a *leading* slash, which means that this is an *absolute* path.

Comment: Ok even without the leading slash, I still get the same error

Comment: what it the *current* directory when you run the program?

Comment: I am sorry for being an idiot, but how do you check that?

Comment: how do you *execute* the python file?

Comment: Oh, I simply called it from the terminal using `python manage.py test`, which runs the tests.py stored in the Django application folder.

Comment: then the directory in which `manage.py` is located is the *current directory*. So that means that in that directory, there should be the `test_data` directory.

Answer (score 0):

import os

try this

```
with open(os.getcwd() + '/test_data/data.json', 'r') as f:
    self.response_data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're opening files in directories close to where your code is, it is common to place

```
import os
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # the directory of this file
```

at the top of the file.

Then you can open files in a `test_data` subdirectory with

```
with open(os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'test_data', 'data.json'), 'rb') as fp:
    self.response_data = json.load(fp)
```

you probably want to open json files, which should be utf-8 encoded, in `'rb'` (read-binary) mode.